# Dilemma of choosing between "much less so" and "much more so"

Tags: word-choice

I just said:

> Is it just me –  but Proposition A does**n't** quite sit right with me, and much **less** so for Proposition B.

Or should I have said:

> Is it just me –  but Proposition A does**n't** quite sit right with me, and much **more** so for Proposition B.

What I meant here is: I disagree with A, and I disagree much **more** with B. The negation by "**not**" complicates the matter, making me unsure which to go for: "**more**" or "**less**"?

Comment: Trust your instinct with *more*. After all, you do not agree with A, and you feel that way even *more* with B.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Hi. Perhaps, my confusion arises from the locution "still less" or "much less" in the sense of "let alone": "I have **nothing** to do with X, **still less** with Y".

Comment: Yes, but you feel stronger against B than A. A doesn't *quite* sit right with you, and B doesn't *at all* sit right with you.

Comment: I think the natural reading would apply *more/less so* to the whole of "doesn't quite sit right ...".

Comment: more and less are not the same ball of wax. That said, much more for and much less for are not grammatical in your sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget that ***so*** in the structure ***more/less so*** normally signifies the ellipsis of an adjective or adverb or even a whole sentence mentioned before:

> The OED says “more so” (as well as “moreso”) is derived from the earlier use of “more” with “***ellipsis of the word or sentence modified***.” That is, it comes from the use of “more” by itself to modify missing words, as in
>
> > I found the first act *delightful* and the second act *even more* [delightful].
>
> Here “delightful” is missing after “more” but understood.
>
> In the OED’s citation from *Emma*, published in 1815, Emma and Mr. Knightley are discussing Harriet’s initial rejection of Mr. Martin:
>
> > ‘I only want to know that Mr. Martin is not very, very bitterly ***disappointed***.’
> > ‘A man cannot be ***more so***,’ was his short, full answer.

([Grammarphopia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2019/10/moreso.html))

The problem with your sentence is that the symmetry of its structure is faulty.

> *[Proposition A doesn't quite sit right with me]* (**1**), and *[much less so for Proposition B]* (**2**).

You have two independent clauses connected by *and*. In (2) the ***subject*** and ***verb*** are omitted, and in such structures they should correspond to the subject and verb of (1), but this makes no sense:

> Proposition A doesn't quite sit right with me, and ***Proposition A sits*** much less so for Proposition B.

Also the PP ***with me*** is replaced in (2) with ***for Proposition B***, which again makes no sense.

What you probably meant is

> Proposition A doesn't quite sit right with me, and ***this is much more the case with*** Proposition B.

You can simplify it using the verb *disagree*, as you suggested:

> I disagree with Proposition A, and much/even more with Proposition B.

Answer (score 1):

OP's context is inherently ambiguous...

> *much **less** so*
> the extent to which Proposition B "sits right" with me is **less** than the (already ***low***) "rightness" of Proposition A.

> *much **more** so*
> the extent to which Proposition B ***doesn't*** "sit right" with me is **more** than the (already ***high***) "**NOT** rightness" of Proposition A.

In context, the intended meaning is obvious (A is ***imperfect***, but B is ***worse***), so I don't think anyone except pedants would even *notice* whether the writer's ***more / less*** was different to what *they* would use.

TEFL contexts excepted, we read / listen to people in order to understand what they're trying to tell us, not to pore over their use of ambiguous idiomatic constructions. Personally, I would use *...much **less** so **does**<sup>1</sup> Proposition B* in OP's context, but if I encountered the ***more*** version outside of ELU/ELL, I wouldn't give it a second thought.

---

<sup>1</sup> Explicitly repeating the relevant verb ***does*** instead of OP's wishy-washy preposition ***for*** should make it even more obvious what's being emphasised.

It also makes it more obvious that the *alternative* to ***less*** here would be *...and much more so **doesn't** B*. Which is really ugly, even though it's perfectly "logical".

Comment: Thank you for the common sense.  I have in the past argued (unsuccessfully) that there is (or ought to be) a rule that if you are  faced with this type of dilemma, then rephrase it altogether.  And, if it's someone else saying this, ask them without being rude or sarcastic.

Comment: @Tuffy: Well, if it's *someone else* saying it, ***and*** the intended sense is obvious, there's no need to say anything at all. And if I'm honest, I suspect that in [almost?] *every* context where someone uses ***much more / less so*** to add emphasis, the basic assertion that's being emphasised is screamingly obvious (you can't really "emphasise" a "vague / ambiguous" point), If as the writer I felt my text wasn't clear, I might rephrase. (But if anyone *suggested* I should rephrase because their blinkered perspective allowed them to claim ambiguity, I'd just tell them where to stick it! :)

Comment: Fingers: I hope I'm allowed to comment simply:  "yes." (>16 characters)